# Schedule alarm from WorkManager

Tags: android

I am trying to schedule an alarm from an androidx.work.Worker but I just can not find a way to acoplish this. I do not have much android knowledge, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager is the best option as far as I know to handle tasks like yours and also is a safer option when dealing with [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

And if you like to use the **AlarmManager** then you can follow this link:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#type

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`

```java
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // get data if you have passed them
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String title = extras.getString("title","");
        String description = extras.getString("description","");

        // do something

    }
}
```

Register it on your AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="you.app.package.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application ...>

        <receiver android:name=".your.package.NotificationReceiver" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

On your worker class's `doWork` method schedule it with `AlarmManager`.

```java
public class ReminderSchedulerWorker extends Worker {

    public final int NOTIFICATION_ALARM_REQ_CODE = 1111;

    public ReminderSchedulerWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", titleString);
        intent.putExtra("description", descriptionString);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_ALARM_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, whichTimeYouWantToScheduleInMillisecond, pendingIntent);        

        return Result.success();
    }

}
```